# substr() PHP not working for array elements

Tags: php, arrays, key-value, substr

```
    $nomadspage = "http://www.nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/";    
    $html = file_get_contents($nomadspage);
    $count = preg_match_all('/<a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a>/i', $html, $files);

    unset($files[1]); //deletes repeat array from preg_match
    $files = $files[0]; //deletes container array from preg_match

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($value, 0, 3) !== "gfs") {
            unset($files[$key]);
        }
    }

    var_dump($files);
```

I have an array with file names from an HTTP directory. I want to filter these files names so that all of the files that don't start with the three letters `gfs` are deleted from the array. However, for some reason, the `substr()` function does not work. It does not pull a substring from the file names. Therefore, the `if` statement does not work. Anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give us a subset of the `$files` array?

Comment: Must be a `preg_match_all()` issue. Like, you're not getting the results you think. Perhaps you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), when you're parsing HTML anyways. Better yet, I'm sure that NOAA information is available as a JSON response, somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$files[0]` contains the strings that match the entire regular expression, so `substr($value, 0, 3)` is always `"<a "`. You should set `$files` to `$files[1]`, not `$files[0]`, it contains all the matches of the `([^"]+)` pattern.

Actually, it's best not to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser library, such as the `DOMDocument` class.